# Реализация ЛВС сервера лицензий для приложения

Tags: c#, сеть, сокет, wcf, лицензирование

Имеется некое приложение в котором часть функционала является платной. Сделана простенькая защита с привязкой к жесткому диску. Т.е. вариант для работы с конкретным единичным пользователем.
Сейчас пришло время создания сервера лицензий для корпоративных решений. Это в первую очередь должно сыграть мне на руку, так как для потенциальных клиентов это удобнее.
Долго гуглил и пришёл к выводу, что есть два варианта решения:

**1. Socket**. Этот вариант я сейчас прорабатываю. В локальной сети запускается приложение (Сервер) в котором указываются данные лицензии из которых получается количество доступных мест. Сервер слушает сеть по определенному порту, а клиенты по этому порту посылают запросы на подключение. В принципе вариант рабочий (правда есть неприятные моменты, которые я пока не решил), но есть и большой минус - где-то в сети должна постоянно работать программа и за которой нужно поглядывать - вдруг она там отвалилась

**2. WCF**. Про этот вариант пока-что знаю совсем поверхностно. Как я это представляю (поправьте, если неправильно) - на компьютерах клиентов устанавливаются службы, которые по локальной сети ходят на сервер и спрашивают разрешения. Приложение клиента обращается к службе и получает результат. Но вот та часть, которая Сервер мне не совсем ясна - это может быть любой компьютер в сети или должен быть именно сервер с Windows Server?

Так вот - в чем вся соль: у меня нет реального опыта работы с сокетами, службами и WCF. Да и с сетями в принципе. Моя специализация, скажем так, немного в другой области. Поэтому я могу в своих поисках сделать неправильный выбор для реализации Сервера лицензий. Вот поэтому я и задаю свой вопрос - хочется услышать от опытных в  подобной теме людей какой из вариантов выбрать и начать копать. Может подскажите еще какую-то альтернативу?

*З.Ы. Да, часть функционала может и платная, но реальной прибыли пока не приносит. Поэтому заказывать разработку у профессионалов я не могу пока себе позволить*

Answer (score 2):

Что сокет, что wcf - суть лишь транспортный уровень для вашего протокола лицензирования. И в том и в другом случае на каком-то вашем компьютере должна крутиться служба ОС виндовс и слушать запросы клиентов и давать ответы. Что лучше умеете - то и выбирайте, хоть http сервер, хоть сокеты, хоть wcf.

Я например, предложил бы сделать именно на базе http сервера - потому что по мне этот вариант проще всего для старта. Но это лишь потому что у меня самого больше опыта с вебом, у вас может быть по-иному. На http будет небольшой оверхэд по сравнению с сокетами, но я бы пренебрёг этим. Простота в разработке будет более важной в этом случае.

Служба WCF не обязана запускаться на серверных редакциях Windows, но вот не рекомендовал бы на WCF завязываться как на технологию.

Ваше приложение будет представлять собой службу ОС windows, можно написать [самостоятельно](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) или использовать готовые фреймворки, которые упрощают написание, скажем Topshelf.

В любом случае у вас будет метод OnStart службы и по этой команде будет включаться прослушивание порта, а по OnStop будет выключаться.

Транспортный уровень можно строить на каком-нибудь легковесном веб-сервере (я много работал с NancyFx), написать свой или использовать майкрософтовский asp.net core mvc (вам от него по сути будет нужно 10% - только раздел про [web api](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.1.php))

> И вот мне не совсем понятно, что из себя должен представлять "Http
>   сервер"? Да и сервер в принципе. Это должно быть приложение?

В принципе лучше сервер лицензирования лучше оформлять как службу ОС windows (этот вариант подходит лучше, если вы вашим клиентам продаёте N копий программы и бесплатно даёте сервер лицензирования-- учтите, что его код будет доступен для изучения) либо альтернативно вы можете не отдавать клиентам сервер лицензии, а держать в интернете собственный сервер, это снижает риск атаки на приложение (но на протокол -- нет). Собственно, не знаю, от каких рисков вам нужно будет страховаться, юрики они часто следят за лицензионной чистотой и даже при возможности крякнуть сервер они предпочтут купить бумажку, чтобы не было проблем при проверках. В случае собственного сервера вы можете хостить приложение в IIS сервере или в любом другом.

Вот вам пример простого сервера лицензий:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LicenceController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST api/licence
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] LicenceRequest request)
        {
            return "mysecretstring";
        }
    }

    public class LicenceRequest
    {
        public string MachineId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И клиент будет на базе обычного HttpClient

```
public class WebRequestHelper
{
    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string uri)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        return await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    }

    public async Task<string> PostFormAsync(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, string jsonString)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");     
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Собственно всё. Основное тут - какие входные данные и что отдавать на выход, чтобы даже зная протокол можно было бы сломать защиту.

Comment: Сейчас читал справку про сервер лицензий JetBrains. Как я понимаю, он работает через http запросы. И нужно скачать и установить сервер лицензий как приложение. Вот примерно тоже самое и я хочу. Подскажите, если работать с http, то что почитать/поизучать?

Comment: И вот мне не совсем понятно, что из себя должен представлять "Http сервер"? Да и сервер в принципе. Это должно быть приложение?

Comment: Я не забивал себе голову сверхзащитой. Что нужно сломать - то сломают. Моя лучшая защита - низкие цены.
Сервер лицензий мне в большей степени нужен для удобства и реализовать его нужно максимально просто для пользователя - поставил, запустил, внес лицензию, забыл.
Вот и серфю в поисках информации. 
Получается, что сам сервер будет "находится" внутри службы? И нужно реализовать программу для доступа или веб-интерфейс?
А на клиентах тоже нужны будут службы? Или можно прям в самого клиента запихать Task с запросами куда-то?

Comment: На клиенте службы скорее всего не нужны. Просто при старте своего приложения будете делать запрос токена (обычным HttpClient) с вашего сервера лицензий - и этого достаточно. Единственная ситуация, в которой я делал бы службу - если ваше приложение само представляет собой службу (я такие приложения видел)

Comment: Я сейчас тупой вопрос спрошу, только не смейтесь =))

А как я WebApi запихну в службу?

Много информации и в голове каша - пытаюсь все разложить по полочкам

Comment: Это не тупой вопрос, это конструктивный вопрос по теме. Смотрите, web api (то, что asp.net core webapi) проще и многим привычнее [запихнуть в IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/?view=aspnetcore-2.1), но и вариант self-host [запихнуть в службу windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1) имеет право на существование.

Comment: Спасибо. Информации получил очень много и изучать теперь придется долго. Как мне кажется - WebApi - хороший вариант. При этом на клиенте мне не нужно делать никаких служб, а просто средствами http запросов обращаться к определенному пути.

Вот только одного никак не могу найти среди кучи всяких статей в интернете. Вот сделал я WebApi - как он устанавливается? Я имею ввиду простое человеческое описание (пример) установки для нубов)) Про IIS ничего тоже не понял.

З.Ы. У меня за сегодня переизбыток определений =))

Comment: Wcf как и webapi можно хостить под unix платформы, использую фронтенд nginx, это удобнее и надёжнее. Данные авторизации надо передавать в бинарном виде, предварительно зашифрованные, иначе все разломают в момент. Ответы тоже надо шифровать, иначе вместо вашего сервера подсунут фэйк. Каждому клиенту разумно кроме лицензии генерить личный сертификат, вами подписанный, им и шифровать.Wcf все же удобнее.

Comment: Да, и клиентская часть по распаковке регистрационных данных должна быть написана не на c#, иначе алгоритм будет известен каждому желающему :) c/c++ подойдёт лучше для этих целей, + binary pack..

Comment: Писал как-то систему защиты с сервером активацией (коммерческую, т.е. её навешивали на другие продукты). Не заморачивайтесь со сверхзащитой и сверхшифрованием. Самое проблемное место в такой схеме - клиентское приложение. Достаточно базового сервера активации (ради учёта) + нормального договора.

Comment: Я уже писал ранее: сверхзащита и свершифрование мне не нужны. В этом нет никакого смысла. Мне нужно сделать максимально просто и для пользователей, и для меня. Вчера пробовал по инструкции развернуть web api на IIS - ничего не заработало. А значит, что этот вариант уже обладает сложностью и подводными камнями (